# Oracle Webcenter Installation

Tags: oracle, portal, webcenter

I am trying to install webcenter on Windows 7 64bit Webcenter setup is not running with 64bit, so i tried with 32 bit install

It started but gives the following error on installation location point.
i am following the points mentioned in blog post

http://yonaweb.be/install_webcenter

PS:I have already installed the Weblogic in MiddlewareNew Location.

**Error:**

> "INST-07286: Specified Oracle Middleware home location does not have version 10.3.4.0 of Weblogic Server. If the version is incorrect then congfiguring with the weblogic server will fail."

This error I got while installing webcenter(11.1.1.5.0) on Windows 64bit, this error coming at "Installation Location" screen level.

Please advise on what steps should I take to move forward my installation successfully

Here I'm putting my installation location details for Middleware "C:\Oracle\MiddlewareNew", and for weblogic "C:\Oracle\MiddlewareNew\wlserver_12.1"

![WebCenter Installation error][1]

Comment: i figured it out i was trying with weblogic 12c which is not compatiable with webcenter 11.1.1.5.

Answer (score 2):

weblogic 12c is not compatible with webcenter yet....change for an earlier version of weblogic 11g and try again

Comment: Yeah, he figured that out in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

The prerequisites for Oracle WenCenter Portal on the official Download page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/portal/downloads/index.html specifies **Oracle WebLogic Server 11g R1** to be used. The latest version *WebLogic Server 12c* does not work with current WenCenter Portal version.